# How to change the message of an airdrop activity?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity, airdrop

I'm sending a URL via AirDrop using a `UIActivityViewController`.  When the receiver gets the alert on their phone, it says "XXX's iPod would like to share xxx".  Is there a way to change this text?  I tried adding an NSString to the items passed to the AirDrop activity, and setting the subject, neither had any effect.  Any way to do this?